# Firefox Failed to start up socket, using mono (c#) on windows 7

Tags: selenium, mono

I really need help, I am new to this field.

I've created simple code on C# to open Firefox by using selenium Lib. I've done my code on Mono (Xamarin 4.0).

If I build and run my code by using .Net runtime, everything is working great. However, when I switch to Mono (3.0.6), I encounter this problem:

> Unhandled Exception:
>       OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to start up socket within 45000
>       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.ConnectToBrowser (Int6
>       4 timeToWaitInMilliSeconds) [0x00000] in :0

Did I miss something? What should I do to solve this problem?
Thank you guys for your help.

**Edit**

Here is my sample code:

> ```
> using System;
> using OpenQA.Selenium;
> using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
> using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
> using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
>
>
> namespace AutomatedTesting
> {
>     class MainTest
>     {
>         public static void Main (string[] args)
>         {
>             IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver ();
>             driver.Navigate ().GoToUrl ("http://www.google.com");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox?

Comment: Hi Arran, thanks for the response, Im using selenium 2.31.0 (for .Net) and Firefox 19.

Comment: Hi Emil, I edit and put my sample code. I just upgrade the selenium to 2.31.2 using NuGet. but still not working.